# Подскажите сервис для проверки логов онлайн на Android

Tags: java, android

Часто приходится клиентам высылать debug.apk приложение чтобы они протестировали, и бывает так что у них возникает ошибка.
В чем ошибка я не знаю. Есть ли легковесная удобная либа чтобы быстро и без проблем одной кнопкой в Android Studio подключить ее к проекту, и использовать ее.

---

Всякие Fabric.io Firebase не предлагайте, они тяжеловесные и часто конфликтуют с другими библиотеками. В итоге для упрощения своей работы мне приходиться ломать голову в 2 раза больше.

Спасибо что дочитали)

Comment: Ничего проще Firebase нет - одна строка в зависимостях и всё. И никаких конфликтов. + бесплатная аналитика. Тоже одной строкой. Итого 2 строки и сразу и ошибки и аналитика

Comment: Что за 2 строки, покажите? Или же это вы сами придумали что там всего 2 строки))

Comment: compile analitics, compile crash. - Две зависимости, 2 строки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может быть Вам подойдет [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). Подключается она довольно [просто](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup).

Возможно настроить отправку репортов либо на электронную почту, либо на свой сервер, либо на свой сервер с их [бэкэндом](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends).

Из коробки доступна возможность отправлять репорты на электронную почту с помощью дефолтного email-клиента, если же Вам нужно отправлять репорты в silent-режиме, то придется все-таки немного [повозиться](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Report-Destinations#implementing-your-own-sender).

Раньше еще можно было отправлять краш-репорты в Google Docs, но сейчас, насколько я знаю, такая возможность отсутствует.